# Missing page numbers, first chapter only - ConTeXt

Tags: page-numbering, context, context-mkiv

I am typesetting books in ConTeXt, and for some reason the first chapter is missing page numbers!

There are correct page numbers in the frontmatter, and correct page numbers in the second chapter and beyond, but in the first chapter they are MIA.

Edit: **Minimal Example:**

I have narrowed down the problem to the following code:

[image]

```
\definepagebreak
        [chapterpagebreak]
        [yes, blank, right]

\setuphead [chapter][page=chapterpagebreak]

\showframe

\starttext
\startchapter
        [title={First Chapter Title}]

\dorecurse{6}{\input knuth \par}

\stopchapter
\startchapter
        [title={Second Chapter Title}]

\dorecurse{6}{\input knuth \par}

\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Comment: As always, a minimal compilable example that reproduces the problem is definitely better. Most of the time you will solve the problem yourself; in case not, well, at least you ease the way to the people here.

Comment: 'Twas on the iPhone, so couldn't copy/paste. I'll add a minimal example tomorrow. Thanks Manuel!

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Try to create a **minimal** example. That is, removing everythibg that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Done @Aditya, sorry for the extra prompting, my first post on Stack Exchange.

Comment: This was a bug in ConTeXt! See [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/90166). It will be fixed in the next beta. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya. Do you know if there's (a) an ETA on the next beta, or (b) a workaround with different code. 

Should I just manually add a blank `\startpagemakeup` or `\page` where necessary in the meantime to make sure chapters start on a recto?

Comment: Usually, there are multiple context beta's every week, so I'll say that the ETA is 2-3 days. If needed, in the meanwhile you can edit `$TEXMF/texmf-context/tex/context/base/page-ini.mkiv`: On line 142, add `\global` before `\pageornamentstate\zerocount` (so that the line will read `\global\pageornamentstate\zerocount`) and then regenerate the format (`context --make` from the command line).

Comment: Made the change, page numbers are now appearing on all first-chapter pages **except** the first verso after the chapter opening - it's still missing.

Comment: @Luke: This is being discussed on the context mailing list (see link above).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was a bug which is solved in updated releases.